# Bootstrap, CSS, JS - Bootstrap file menubar hover after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make an application making use of twitter's bootstrap framework. I have a navbar that functions like a File Menu bar with File/Edit/Help/etc.

I like the fact that you need to click to make the dropdown appear, however how can I make it where it will dropdown the Edit menu for instance when moving from the File menu (after it is clicked and dropped down).

An example of this is going to google docs, clicking one menu and then moving to another menu item it will dropdown the new hovered menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: for your `<ul>` element make two classes.
One for example `doc-menu` other `normal-menu`.
On menu item click: your `<li>` should get `class="active"` and `<ul class="doc-menu"`.
Then show up inner `<ul><li>....</ul>` inside `<li class="active">` and keep it up even if not hovered. On other `doc-menu` item hover you change the active class to other `<li>` element. This can be done by listening to [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onmouseover) using javascript. When clicked on background or inner `<ul><li>....</ul>` change `<ul class="doc-menu">` to `<ul class="normal-menu>`